# Drive picker upload to a team drive as opposed to personal google drive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drive, google-app-maker

Right now I have a relational datasource that holds the attachment name, link, date uploaded and who uploaded it. When you select a file with the drive picker widget it always uploads the file to your own personal drive. Is there a way to set the path for where the file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet on this one is to use the moveFile() method the server scripting library provided by AMU:

```
function moveFile(id, email){
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id); 
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('M9jYgpQ1giX29lWUdWQmo5SzA').addFile(file);
 DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file); 

 if(email){
   setFileOwner(id, email);
 }
```

You can get the folder id out of the URL of your drive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking upload to Google Team Drive instead of Google Drive?

If that is your question, you might need to go a long-route, to my knowledge, it still can not directly modify the upload path in Drive Picker Widget.

You can see some similar answer here: 
[Google Drive API uploading a file to team drive in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206693/google-drive-api-uploading-a-file-to-team-drive-in-javascript)